# How to make my app icon on twitter appear when I attempt to log in using twitter

Tags: swift, firebase, twitter, authentication

I would like to know how can I add my app logo on the left side of this screen showing below.

Tried changing it on the developer.twitter.com website but it didn't worked, is this via a handler?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8uDd.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I would give it some time. Sometimes it takes a while for the picture to update everywhere after updating it on `developer.twitter.com`

Comment: Hi rpecka, have you had this issue before with your projects?

Comment: Yeah. The same thing happens with Facebook